# Could not open proj generic class cache for build file & Unsupported class file major version 63

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

Without any change to android React Native 0.70/gradle 7.5.1/MacOS Monetary app, there throws an error when doing `npx react-native run-android`. Here is the error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'xyz_app6'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file '/Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/android/build.gradle' (/Users/macair/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/4fbdrhtkb1gqd0m7r89rbb30y).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63
```

Here is the ls output under /Users/macair/:

```
 0 drwxr-xr-x   10 macair  staff    320 Aug  4 01:19 .gradle
```

The error seems out of nowhere. Deleting `./gradle/7.5.1` didn't help. Before today, the Android version of the app was working fine and there is no change made to it. Also the IOS version of the app is working fine.

UPDATE:
`/usr/libexec/java_home` output is:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/19/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

`java --version` output is:

```
openjdk 19 2022-09-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 19)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 19, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After brew install JDK 17 and choose JDK 17 for app in android studio->project structure. add JAVA_HOME pointing to JDK 17 to .zshrc (MacOS Monetary). `npx react-native run-android` launched successfully.

Comment: thank you, interestingly JDK 19 stopped working after I updated my dependencies(packages, I'm a Flutter developer)

Comment: I had the same problem. I've installed JDK 19 on my Mac and it stopped working. After closing my Android Studio, uninstalling JDK 19 and reuse JDK 17, opening Android Studio again (what creates the new gradle build) everything worked again. In my case `expo run:android`

Answer (score 0):

I was using JDK version 19, Switching to version 17 solved my issue.