# Getting error after updating android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

I update android studio and now i am getting this tried tried different ways but not work for me.`Build file 'D:\StudioProjects\untitled1\android\build.gradle' line: 26

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'D:\StudioProjects\untitled1\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\ARC.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\5j806ry1k8j18kre88jnws39s).
> > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> `

Comment: Have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/74596486

Comment: tried but now working in my case

Comment: Try to update your gradle to the latest version. Process:
[Upgrade Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920708/update-gradle-in-flutter-project)